# Scrollbar for one direction, but overflow visible in another

Tags: css, overflow

I have this element I'm trying to develop where on the X axis, I need to scroll, but on the Y axis, I would need to see the overflow.

Its selects where you may scroll through the selects, but when you open one you need to still see the options.

But when I ask 'overflow-x:scroll', the overflow-y is forced to scroll or be hidden. overflow-y is ignored.

Is there a way to make it so the overflow on the x is kept on scroll (or is scrollable) but the y axis can still overflow its container?

EDIT: Added a quick example of how my code looks and what I'm working with.

```css
.scroller {
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 16px 0;
}

.select {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.selectLabel {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.selectOptions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="select">
    <div class="selectLabel">Hello</div>
    <div class="selectOptions">
      Hello<br /> World
      <br /> And
      <br /> Stack
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="select">
    <div class="selectLabel">Hello</div>
    <div class="selectOptions">
      Hello<br /> World
      <br /> And
      <br /> Stack
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="select">
    <div class="selectLabel">Hello</div>
    <div class="selectOptions">
      Hello<br /> World
      <br /> And
      <br /> Stack
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="select">
    <div class="selectLabel">Hello</div>
    <div class="selectOptions">
      Hello<br /> World
      <br /> And
      <br /> Stack
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="select">
    <div class="selectLabel">Hello</div>
    <div class="selectOptions">
      Hello<br /> World
      <br /> And
      <br /> Stack
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: visible;
```

Comment: That is exactly how its made currently. And overflow-y is ignored.

Comment: It's likely something else is causing the issue then - could you share the page or the rest of the code?

Comment: Added a code snippet to show whatever i'm working with. Its not the exact thing I'm working with, but it does have the same result.